# How to Setup Bulk In/Out USB Endpoints for OTG peripheral in PetaLinux 2016.3

Tags: bulk, usb-otg, petalinux

I am presently designing a peripheral device with a ZC702 board using PetaLinux.  The examples provided for USB OTG peripherals are either mass storage or Ethernet over USB.  Both of these examples work with the board.  I am now trying to implement the board as a simple OTG peripheral with a Bulk In/Out set of endpoints so I can just send bulk transfer commands to it and have the board send back bulk responses.  The chipidea driver is expecting a function to be setup under the usb gadget.  The previous functions for mass storage and Ethernet were accomplished by creating directories for mass_storage.ms0 and rndis.rn0, respectively.  When I don't create a function, it gives me an error saying there is no function when I call echo "ci_hdrc.0" > UDC.  Here are my calls from the prompt once PetaLinux is booted up:

```
zynq> mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
zynq> insmod /mnt/configfs.ko
zynq> insmod /mnt/libcomposite.ko
zynq> mount -t configfs none /sys/kernel/config
zynq> cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget
zynq> mkdir g1
zynq> cd g1
zynq> echo "64" > bMaxPacketSize0
zynq> echo "0x200" > bcdUSB
zynq> echo "0x100" > bcdDevice
zynq> echo "0x0114" > idVendor
zynq> echo "0x0019" > idProduct
zynq> mkdir strings/0x409
zynq> cd strings
zynq> cd 0x409
zynq> echo “0123456789” > serialnumber
zynq> echo “My Company” > manufacturer
zynq> echo “MyDevice” > product
zynq> mkdir configs/c1.1
zynq> echo "ci_hdrc.0" > UDC
```

How do I implement an OTG peripheral device with Bulk endpoints?  Any resources that might help me on this journey?

Thanks.

Comment: I would also be interested in this. Too bad no answer has been given. @teastham: Did you get anywhere with this?